# Use Python script to check whether or not a program is hung/crashed in Windows? Also, Pipes

Tags: python, pipe

I have 2 questions, so I figured I would cram them into 1 single post instead of filling the board up with useless information

Simple description of situation: I am attempting to create a python script that opens an executable for a simple C++ program with an unknown number of inputs in a windows environment, sends some data into that program, and then check to see if it has crashed / rinse and repeat.

**Question 1:** This is a pipes question. Bear with me, I am still learning about pipes, so I may have a misunderstanding of exactly how they work. Forgive me if I do. Is it possible to detect how many inputs a program has? Basically what I'm attempting to do is open an executable using my python script, that I personally know nothing about, and send in garbage data into each available input. If it is NOT possible to detect how many inputs there are: would there be an adverse reaction (like crashing the program Im sending the data into) if I send more arguments into it than there are inputs? As in the C++ program takes 3 inputs and I send in 6 arguments?

**Question 2:** Does anyone know if it possible using a python script to detect whether a program has hung or not? So far the best information on this I've been able to find is simply detecting whether the program is running or not via FindWindow, and then I suppose I could monitor the CPU usage to see if it continues to rise... but that is hardly an ideal method (and may not even work properly!) If there are any better known methods out there I would be thrilled!

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Answer to Question 2

You should look into investigating psutil, hosted @ https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil .  I don't know whether you'll find what you're looking for, but pusutil is a decent API, offering access to info such as number of CPUs in addition to process information, which is what you want.